# SSRS Report is 'dropping' rows.

Tags: reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio Pro 2013 to design reports.

My Dataset Query returns around a thousand rows of data - but the report only displays one-third of that.

There is no filter in the Tablix or in the Dataset.

Is there somewhere else that a filter can be lurking in the Report?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There can also be filters on row groupings. How did you come up with the thousand rows? Did you capture that with SQL Profiler?

Comment: if you dont have filters in sql query, the only reason the report shows less data is there might be filter applied on the report site. there are options for filter in dataset, tablix, group. try to export the report data in excel and verify.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: the 'thousand' rows is a ballpark - but I ran the Dataset Query in SSMS. The number of rows the query returns is also the exact number that the Report is displaying in a Total field that uses this Expr: =Count(Fields!FieldName.Value). But when I physically count the rows in the actual report, I get around 400 rows.

Comment: . . . and that is another thing that bothers me about this report. I cannot get it to calculate the actual number of rows that it is displaying. However I have tried [including Row-Count() ...] I still get the number of rows that the Dataset is returning - not the number of rows that are actually ON the report. I've been searching high & low for a solution to that but have not been able to make anything work.

Comment: P.S. There is only the Row Group 'Details - and the only thing happening in there is three Group By fields.

Comment: It sounds like some of your data is being aggregated with your 3 **GROUP BY** fields. If you add an extra column with `=COUNTROWS()` you wlll probably see that some have more that one row. If you want all the detail, remove the **3 GROUP BY** fields from your **details**.

Comment: @Hannover Fist: Thanks! That was it. Many of the report rows were aggregations of more than one row of actual data. Appreciate your help. I don't know how I can mark yours as the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it helped. I guess I should add this as an answer in case any has a similar situation in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some of your data is being aggregated with your 3 **GROUP BY** fields.

> There is only the Row Group 'Details - and the only thing happening in
>   there is three Group By fields

If you add an extra column with `=COUNTROWS()` you wlll probably see that some have more that one row.

If you want all the detail, remove the 3 **GROUP BY** fields from your details.